# Jmeter - how to array values in POST data

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have added regular expression extractor and able to obtain the taskid value, but when i have multiple task id's in same request, how to handle them ?

Here is my POST data:
It's sending same taskid over and over again, instead of picking different taskid's from the payload request

[{"state":"COMPLETED","taskId":"345836","properties":[{"value":"2018-08-01T18:36:41.635Z","id":"deliveryDate"}]},{"state":"COMPLETED","taskId":"345836","properties":[{"value":"2018-08-01T18:36:41.635Z","id":"deliveryDate"}]}]

Here is my Payload request:
[image: Payload Request]

Instead of taking different Task ID's , its using the same Task ID's again and again.

Please suggest what needs to be done to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

To get different results in [Regular expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) you need to change Match No. either

> Use a value of zero to indicate JMeter should choose a match at random.

Or use

> Negative numbers are used in conjunction with the [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

Comment: This option didnt work for me, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue by using , Json extractor.
[image]